# Entity Framework 6 Lazy Loading not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having some trouble with EF6 lazy loading, code first to an existing database.

Here are the Entities that are giving me the issue, I have no idea why it is not working, everything I find online says it should be working.

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the configuration mappings:

```
public class Token
{
    public long TokenId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid TokenValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

    public TokenMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.TokenId);

        this.Property(t => t.TokenValue)
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.ExpirationDate)
            .IsRequired();

        this.ToTable("Tokens");
        this.Property(t => t.TokenId).HasColumnName("TokenId");
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
        this.Property(t => t.TokenValue).HasColumnName("TokenValue");
        this.Property(t => t.ExpirationDate).HasColumnName("ExpirationDate");

        this.HasRequired(s => s.User)
            .WithMany(s=>s.Tokens)
            .HasForeignKey(s=>s.UserId);
    }


    public UserMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.HasKey(t => t.UserId);
        this.Property(t => t.Email)
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .IsRequired();

        this.HasMany(t => t.Businesses)
            .WithMany(set => set.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("BusinessUser");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("BusinessId");
            });

        this.HasMany(s => s.Tokens)
            .WithRequired(s => s.User)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId);

        this.HasMany(s => s.Candidates)
            .WithOptional(s => s.User)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId);
    }
```

And here is a few snippets from the context:

```
    public DbSet<Token> Token { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TokenMap()); 
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());

    }
```

Whenever I do a SingleOrDefault on the Tokens entity the result' user is null.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? All the data in the database is right, and UserId does have a value.

Here is a more elaborate example of calling:

I am implementing the repository patern.

In the class doing the call' constructor I have:

```
context = new Consolid8ContextProvider();
uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
```

And then `uow.Tokens.First(u => u.ExpirationDate > DateTime.Now && u.TokenValue == token);`

Tokens is my TokenRepository that exposes the Tokens entity, and First is a wrapper for FirstOrDefault.

This results in a token object with all of the properties set except for the User navigation property

Comment: Could you show code that get data from database? And where you look at user property. Are you sure that your context is not closed between this two events?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I did an update

Comment: Another note is that I know my repo pattern is correct because it works like a charm using database first design

Comment: Is it a many to many mapping? Does a user have the token you are looking at? Check the database :)

Comment: Is the `Token` that is returned by `SingleOrDefault` a dynamic proxy? You can check that in the debugger by looking at the object's type name. It should be a proxy, otherwise lazy loading won't work. Did you possibly set `LazyLoadingEnabled` or `ProxyCreationEnabled` to `false`?

Comment: @Slauma sorry but where in the debugger can I view that? Nope didn't set LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled to false, they are on default values which is as far as I know true

Comment: Just inspect the `Token` object that is returned by `SingleOrDefault` (set breakpoint after that line and hover over the variable). If it shows as type name something like `DynamicProxy_xyz...` (or similar with some long cryptic guid) it's a proxy. If it just shows `<YourNamespace>.Token` it's not.

Comment: @slauma so how do I get it to be a proxy then?

Comment: Are you saying that it's not a proxy? EF should do that automatically if all proxy requirements are met (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100)). However, from what I see in your code snippets they are (if the class definitions your are showing are complete).

Comment: @Slauma Yes it is not a proxy, the model classes that I provided are complete definitions. And it matches all the requirements that you are referring to.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Maybe you could show how your repo looks like (especially the implementation of `uow.Tokens.First...`) down to the point where you access the actual `context.Token` DbSet.

Comment: @Slauma a quick note, my DBContext is wrapped in the BreezeJS EFContextProvider

Comment: @Slauma ok so breezejs disables lazyloading and proxycreation by default, is there a way to enabled it for certain requests only without setting it to true for all requests?

Comment: `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` and `ProxyCreationEnabled = true` is set per context instance. So, you could set it in one and not in the other situation. But I have not really a clue about breeze, not sure if it's a good idea. Perhaps you create better a new question with "breeze" tag that focusses on that particular problem.

Comment: @Slauma Thanks for all the help, it is appreciated, i think it might be best if we remove this question, don't see any help in this for the community

Comment: If you write your own answer that you use breeze and breeze set lazyloading and proxycreation to `false` by default it might help others not to fall into the same trap. Seems OK to me as question result.

Comment: BTW: You can try to set the two flags to `true` right before your `uow.Tokens.First...` (perhaps with a new uow method `EnableLazyLoading` or so). It's not required to set it when the context is created, you can do it before you run a particular query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was using BreezeJS and it overrides your context with it's own settings, part of which is to set LazyLoading and EnableProxiesCreation to false.

So if you want to do queries outside of breeze you either have to implement a different constructor for your breeze provider or setting it per query as Slauma has suggested in the comments of the question.